# OpenVPN connection ok but no Internet access

Tags: openvpn, nat, internet

I'm learning to use OpenVPN and I bought a VPS with OpenVPN (a default installation offered by the hosting provider).

When I configure my client to connect to the server, I notice that the connection is established but I can't browse.

It suposes that the installation is ready to go. Maybe some network configuration is wrong, but I can't find the mistakes.

## 1. Server Settings

### 1.1 Basic configuration

[image]

### 1.2 VPN Settings

[image]

[image]

### 1.3 Network

```
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  P-t-P:10.0.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t1     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.0.0.129  P-t-P:10.0.0.129  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:51.xx.xx.xxx  Bcast:51.xx.xx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:83862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:8108403 (7.7 MiB)  TX bytes:11762035 (11.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:61294 (59.8 KiB)  TX bytes:61294 (59.8 KiB)
```

### 1.4 iptables

The following rule was added:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Return of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere            anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere            anywhere
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere            anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_ACCEPT  udp  --  anywhere            xxx.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu   state NEW udp dpt:openvpn
AS0_ACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere            xxx.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu   state NEW tcp dpt:https
AS0_WEBACCEPT  all  --  anywhere         anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_WEBACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere         xxx.ip-xx-xx-xx.eu   state NEW tcp dpt:943

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere            anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere            anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_OUT_S2C  all  --  anywhere           anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_OUT_LOCAL  all  --  anywhere         anywhere

Chain AS0_ACCEPT (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_IN (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.1
           all  --  default              anywhere
AS0_IN_POST  all  --  anywhere           anywhere

Chain AS0_IN_NAT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK or 0x8000000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_IN_POST (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/24
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_IN_PRE (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             link-local/16
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_IN_ROUTE (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK or 0x4000000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_OUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_OUT_POST  all  --  anywhere          anywhere

Chain AS0_OUT_LOCAL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp redirect
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_OUT_POST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_OUT_S2C (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_IN_NAT  all  --  anywhere            172.27.224.0/20
AS0_IN_POST  all  --  anywhere           anywhere

Chain AS0_WEBACCEPT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Return of `iptables -t nat -nL`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0  0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_NAT_PRE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0          0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0

Chain AS0_NAT (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:51.xx.xx.xxx
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain AS0_NAT_PRE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AS0_NAT    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x8000000/0x8000000
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0         169.254.0.0/16
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0         192.168.0.0/16
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0         172.16.0.0/12
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  0.0.0.0/0         10.0.0.0/8
AS0_NAT    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain AS0_NAT_TEST (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x4000000/0x4000000
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/24
AS0_NAT    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

### 1.5 Additional configuration

The `/etc/sysctl.conf` was edited uncommenting the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Return of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

## 2. Client Settings

When I connect to the VPN, the client has the following configuration:

```
IPv6: fe80::159:2b87:b731:8337%6
IPv4: 10.0.0.130
Mask: 255.255.255.128
Gateway: 10.0.0.129
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your VPN settings, we can see the network address is set to 172.27.224.0/20

Looking at your Group Default IP Address Network setting, you would use 172.27.240.0/20

You did add an iptables rules that would NAT egress trafic from 172.27.240.0/20.

Yet your client is connected as 172.27.232.1/21. As such, its traffic is not subjet to your NAT rule.

Either change your NAT rule, including both 172.27.240/20 and 172.27.224/20, or remove the Group Default IP Address Network setting/only NAT 172.27.224/20.

Comment: I tried the configuration you said, but still can't access to Internet. After, I changed all the VPN settings using a new IP and mask, and the result is the same. I updated the post with the new configuration and I added the complete iptables settings.

Comment: okay, now this is weird, ... You're quoting your sysctl.conf, but are you sure that setting was applied (run `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` to be sure). Can we check the nat tables as well (`iptables -t nat -nL`)? When in doubt, you could use tcpdump on your vpn interface, then eth0, making sure traffic goes through. Or figuring out why it doesn't.

Comment: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` checked: it returns `1`. The result of `iptables -t nat -nL` was added to post. Not sure how to use tcpdump. I will take a look.

Comment: Sounds good. AFAIU, you didn't need to add your own NAT rule, you already had one. Looks good anyway. you can use `tcpdump -vvni as0t1` for communications within your VPN tunnel, `tcpdump -vvni eth0 port not 22 and port not 443` matching what leaves your server, `tcpdump -vvni eth0 \( tcp and port 443 \) or \( udp and port 1194 \)` to see VPN communications.